# Series where every element contains a mean of near elements

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, recurrence-relations, numerical-linear-algebra

I wonder if already exists a solution to this problem:
I must calculate the value of every element of a time series (a finite series of numbers) where every element equals the mean of an easily evaluable value, and of the two elements nearby (the one before and the one after). For the first and the last element of the series just the following or the previous element contribution appears.

Actually the precise weights are the following:

$$K_i= \frac{3}{4}K_i^{(0)} + \frac{1}{8}K_{i-1} + \frac{1}{8}K_{i+1}$$

Do you know what's the best algorithm or method to solve this problem?

edit: I don't need an exact solution, which I understand would not be reasonable, because I do need an  efficient solution.

Comment: I wonder whether the coefficients should be two times larger. It would be closer to "every element equals the mean of an easily evaluable constant, and of the two elements nearby". Though also not completely, this corresponds rather to the coefficients $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$...

Comment: It's a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: This is a system of linear equations in the unknowns $K_i$. Have you tried solving that system using linear algebra?

Comment: I tried of course, but it's not simple. At least I couldn't solve it yet

Comment: Please give the values of the coefficients for both boundary cases as well. Otherwise a particularly simple solution can hardly be expected.

Comment: sorry I don't understand what coefficients are you talking about and what do you mean when you write "boundary cases". also, I need a general solution

Comment: The coefficients are the numbers, which in your example are (3/4,1/8,1/8). I asked you to give the coefficients for computation of the first and of the last $K$. What do you mean by "a general solution"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system is in the form

$$aK_{i-1}+bK_i+cK_{i+1}=d_i,$$ which is called a tridiagonal system.

There is a classical method to efficiently solve such systems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm

In your case, the coefficients are known constants, and it might be possible to compute the matrix inverse once for all.

Comment: unfortunatly it's not, it is more like the form $ad_{i-1} + bK_i + cd_{i+1} = d_i$

Comment: @carlo Unfortunately either you misunderstand your own problem or cannot formulate it correctly.

Comment: that's right. I really missed something obvious when studing this answere, tomorrow  I will give it a second look

Comment: @carlo: what you write is in the same tridiagonal form, so what ?

Comment: it only took me a second look to understand that your solution is fully valid. thank you